# Issue with Dynamic Data on WooCommerce Archive Page - Replacing Add to Cart with Product Inquiry Button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, elementor

I want to replace the add to cart button with a product inquiry button, so that visitors can see the product inquiry button instead of the add to cart button. I am using Elementor forms to display dynamic data such as product image and title on a popup on the archive page. The form works well on the single product page, but not on the archive page. It only shows the first product name and image by default.

I used the following code to remove the button and open the popup, but I cannot get the data.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hello_elementor_child_scripts_styles', 20);

// Remove the "Add to Cart" button
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_add_to_cart_button', 10);

function remove_add_to_cart_button() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
}

// Add the "Get Price" button
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_get_price_button', 11);

function add_get_price_button($product) {
    if (is_a($product, 'WC_Product')) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $product_title = $product->get_title();
        $product_description = $product->get_description();
        $product_url = $product->get_permalink();

        echo '<a href="#elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjM4MiIsInRvdGdsZSI6ZmFsc2V9&product_id=' . esc_attr($product_id) . '" class="button get_price_button" data-product-id="' . esc_attr($product_id) . '" data-product-title="' . esc_attr($product_title) . '" data-product-description="' . esc_attr($product_description) . '" data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes" data-elementor-lightbox-id="382">Get Price</a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no available `$product` variable argument in `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` hook… Try the following revised code instead:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hello_elementor_child_scripts_styles', 20);

// Remove the "Add to Cart" button
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_add_to_cart_button', 10);
function remove_add_to_cart_button() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
}

// Add the "Get Price" button
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_get_price_button', 11);
function add_get_price_button() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    }

    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $product_title = $product->get_title();
        $product_description = $product->get_description();
        $product_url = $product->get_permalink();

        echo '<a href="#elementor-action%3Aaction%3Dpopup%3Aopen%26settings%3DeyJpZCI6IjM4MiIsInRvdGdsZSI6ZmFsc2V9&product_id=' . esc_attr($product_id) . '" class="button get_price_button" data-product-id="' . esc_attr($product_id) . '" data-product-title="' . esc_attr($product_title) . '" data-product-description="' . esc_attr($product_description) . '" data-elementor-open-lightbox="yes" data-elementor-lightbox-id="382">Get Price</a>';
    }
}
```

It should work.